# In hyperledger fabric How to pass two orderer's in peer channel create?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm exploring the Hyperledger fabric with Kafka based ordering,
When I try to create a channel using CLI, I need to pass the orderer.

I have created two orderers now using Kafka, But how to pass two orderers while creating the channel.

```
peer channel create -o orderer0.example.com,**orderer1.example.com**
```

Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you cant. Because when you use orderer-kafka, when you send a transacción to one orderer he will use a kafka brokers to "broadcast" the transaction to all orderers on the Network.

Comment: I agree with your point, Suppose I create channel with orderer0.example.com. It will broadcast with other orderers. But if I stop the orderer0.example.com. How the fault tolerance will be handled. Because the channel is created only with orderer0.example.com

Comment: No, when you create the Channel  (with configtx) and submit to the orderer, he will create the first block that have the initial configuration of the channel (Orgs, Policy, etc). When this process is done, the orderer will broadcast the block to all orderers (This should be the first block). The block have the information of all orderers in the network. After this, you can send transactions to orderer1.example.com because he has the all configuration of the channel, the orderer node has a copy of the ledger, like a peer node.